# How to Query to Find out if a Table has a CLUSTERED Primary Key

Tags: sql, t-sql, primary-key, clustered-index

I found this question, but it doesn't appear to answer the question...

[SQL Server - How to find if clustered index exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581508/sql-server-how-to-find-if-clustered-index-exists)

How can I write an IF T-SQL statement to say:

```
IF NOT ([TableName] has a CLUSTERED PK)
   ALTER TABLE to add the CLUSTERED PK
```

Comment: How about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091826/find-tables-without-clustered-index-but-with-primary-keys-on-a-table

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM sys.indexes 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MdsInventar') 
                 AND index_id = 1
                 AND is_primary_key = 1)
   ......
```

The clustered index always has `index_id` = 1. Of course - if you check like this (with the `is_primary_key = 1` condition), then there's always a chance that there might be a **non-primary** clustered index on the table already - so you won't be able to create another clustered index. So maybe you need to lose the `AND is_primary_key = 1` condition and check just for "is there a clustered index".

**Update:** or if using `index_id = 1` seems black magic to you, you can also use the `type` column instead:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM sys.indexes 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MdsInventar') 
                 AND type = 1
                 AND is_primary_key = 1)
   ......
```

Comment: I think it would be more self-describing to filter on the index type instead of the (kind of) magic index_id.

Comment: @usr: yes, you could do that, too - but `index_id = 1` is hardly "magic" - [it's well known, well documented](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173760.aspx) ... Also: knowing that `type = 1` is the clustered index also is kinda "magic", no?

Comment: You could also check whether it is a HEAP (nonclustered) or not (clustered):
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MdsInventar') AND type_desc = 'HEAP'
but then you need to change the IF NOT EXISTS to IF EXISTS

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it is still the issue but maybe it will help another person.

Please find below portion of the code:

```
SELECT COL_NAME(ic.object_id,ic.column_id) AS 'column name', 
i.object_id, i.name, i.type_desc, ds.name, ds.type_desc FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces ds ON i.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id 
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
WHERE i.object_id = OBJECT_ID('NameOfYourTableWithSchemaIncluded')
```

Hope it helps anyone!
Best Regards.