# SQL Replace All Tables with Clustered Columnstore Index

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2016, data-warehouse, columnstore

We are conducting a migration project, and looking to replace most Rowstore indexes with Clustered Columnstore indexes for large Data Warehouse. We are adding a unique index on the identity column.

Does anyone have script to alter run through all 100+ tables, and replace primary key clustered index with Columnstore Index?

Testing to see if columnstore index will help performance tuning if we migrate.

*By the way, are Identity columns recommended in Columnstore? Need way to identify each row (sometimes identity columns may reset, so placing unique constraint, Or should Guids be used?) If not identity, feel free to remove identity column with Guid or something else .

**Current:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fact_SalesTransaction] 
(
    [FactSalesTransactionId]        INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DimCustomerId]                 INT              NOT NULL,
    [DimSellerId]                   INT              NOT NULL,
    [SalesDatetime]                 DATETIME         NULL,
    [DimSalesDateId]                INT              NULL,
    [SalesAmount]                   DECIMAL (28, 2)  NULL,
    [ETLCreateDate]                 DATETIME         NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk_SalesTransactionId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SalesTransactionId] ASC)
);
```

**Expected:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fact_SalesTransaction] 
(
    [FactSalesTransactionId]        INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DimCustomerId]                 INT              NOT NULL,
    [DimSellerId]                   INT              NOT NULL,
    [SalesDatetime]                 DATETIME         NULL,
    [DimSalesDateId]                INT              NULL,
    [SalesAmount]                   DECIMAL (28, 2)  NULL,
    [ETLCreateDate]                 DATETIME         NULL,
);


CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX ccx_Fact_SalesTransaction ON Fact_SalesTransaction;  

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unx_FactSalesTransactionId ON dbo.Fact_SalesTransaction (FactSalesTransactionId);
```

We only want to use T-SQL to conduct this on an existing database.

Helpful Resource in Comment: [Generate SQL Create Scripts for existing tables with Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query)

Comment: have you tried the brent ozar blog?

Comment: Do all of your rowstore tables have only a primary key clustered index and no other indexes or foreign key constraints that need to be preserved?

Comment: I wrote something similar last year to archive a lot of data. I queried sys.tables and sys.columns and so on to get all the references and then wrote dynamic sql to generate scripts that would produce the structure to copy to. Would this work for you? Have you tried to get metadata from sys.tables to work from?

Comment: I found something that you can use as a reference to build a script to make your table code from metadata. Looks like it has everything you need right there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you need to change your primary key clustered constraint under 'current' to point to FactSalesTransactionId instead of 'SalesTransactionId'.

Comment: this question is always open, if anyone wants to add more optimized responses, feel free, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devart answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query) question asking about how to generate a script for a table.  I tweaked his code to omit the primary key portion and replaced it with unique key and columnstore creation scripts following his general pattern.  I also had to use marc_s's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167631/how-to-query-to-find-out-if-a-table-has-a-clustered-primary-key) question about how to find out if a table's primary key is clustered or not.  I put all this into a stored procedure called #scriptTable.  This is what's below:

```
create procedure #scriptTable
    @table_name sysname,
    @sql nvarchar(max) output
as

DECLARE 
      @object_name SYSNAME
    , @object_id INT

SELECT 
      @object_name = '[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + ']'
    , @object_id = o.[object_id]
FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE s.name + '.' + o.name = @table_name
    AND o.[type] = 'U'
    AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0

;WITH index_column AS 
(
    SELECT 
          ic.[object_id]
        , ic.index_id
        , ic.is_descending_key
        , ic.is_included_column
        , c.name
    FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
    WHERE ic.[object_id] = @object_id
),
fk_columns AS 
(
     SELECT 
          k.constraint_object_id
        , cname = c.name
        , rcname = rc.name
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns k WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns rc WITH (NOWAIT) ON rc.[object_id] = k.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id 
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
    WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id
)
SELECT @sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @object_name + CHAR(13) + '(' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(9) + ', [' + c.name + '] ' + 
        CASE WHEN c.is_computed = 1
            THEN 'AS ' + cc.[definition] 
            ELSE UPPER(tp.name) + 
                CASE WHEN tp.name IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary', 'text')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar', 'ntext')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('datetime2', 'time2', 'datetimeoffset') 
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name = 'decimal' 
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                    ELSE ''
                END +
                CASE WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL THEN ' COLLATE ' + c.collation_name ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ' NULL' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END +
                CASE WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN ' DEFAULT' + dc.[definition] ELSE '' END + 
                CASE WHEN ic.is_identity = 1 THEN ' IDENTITY(' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, '0') AS CHAR(1)) + ',' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value, '1') AS CHAR(1)) + ')' ELSE '' END 
        END + CHAR(13)
    FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.types tp WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns cc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1 AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    WHERE c.[object_id] = @object_id
    ORDER BY c.column_id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CHAR(9) + ' ')
    + ')'  + CHAR(13)
    + ISNULL((SELECT (
        SELECT CHAR(13) +
             'ALTER TABLE ' + @object_name + ' WITH' 
            + CASE WHEN fk.is_not_trusted = 1 
                THEN ' NOCHECK' 
                ELSE ' CHECK' 
              END + 
              ' ADD CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + '] FOREIGN KEY(' 
              + STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + k.cname + ']'
                FROM fk_columns k
                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')' +
              ' REFERENCES [' + SCHEMA_NAME(ro.[schema_id]) + '].[' + ro.name + '] ('
              + STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + k.rcname + ']'
                FROM fk_columns k
                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')'
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON DELETE CASCADE' 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON DELETE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' 
                ELSE '' 
              END
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON UPDATE CASCADE'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT'  
                ELSE '' 
              END 
            + CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE ' + @object_name + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + ']' + CHAR(13)
        FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.objects ro WITH (NOWAIT) ON ro.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
        WHERE fk.parent_object_id = @object_id
        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')), '')
    + ISNULL(((SELECT
         CHAR(13) + 'CREATE' + CASE WHEN i.is_unique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE' ELSE '' END 
                + ' NONCLUSTERED INDEX [' + i.name + '] ON ' + @object_name + ' (' +
                STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']' + CASE WHEN c.is_descending_key = 1 THEN ' DESC' ELSE ' ASC' END
                FROM index_column c
                WHERE c.is_included_column = 0
                    AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'  
                + ISNULL(CHAR(13) + 'INCLUDE (' + 
                    STUFF((
                    SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']'
                    FROM index_column c
                    WHERE c.is_included_column = 1
                        AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')', '')  + CHAR(13)
        FROM sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT)
        WHERE i.[object_id] = @object_id
            AND i.is_primary_key = 0
            AND i.[type] = 2
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ), '')
    + char(13)

-- Replaced "create primary key" logic in the original with what's below:

    +   ISNULL(
            (
                select  'create clustered columnstore index [ccx_' + @table_name + '] on ' + @object_name + char(13) +
                        'create unique ' + convert(nvarchar(max), i.type_desc) + ' index [' + replace(k.name, 'pk_', 'unx_') + '] ' +
                            'on ' + @object_name + ' (' + 
                                (
                                    SELECT STUFF((
                                        SELECT  ', [' + ic.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END
                                        FROM    index_column ic
                                        WHERE   ic.is_included_column = 0
                                        AND     ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id 
                                        AND     ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id     
                                        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE
                                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
                                ) + 
                            ')' + CHAR(13)
                FROM sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT)
                join sys.indexes i with (nowait) on k.unique_index_id = i.index_id and k.parent_object_id = i.object_id
                WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id 
                    AND k.[type] = 'PK'
            ), 
            ''
        );
```

You can use #scriptTable like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
exec #scriptTable 'dbo.Fact_SalesTransaction', @sql output;
print (@sql);
```

Replace 'print' with 'exec' or use sp_executeSql when ready.

To use it on all tables, first capture the tables you want to modify:

```
declare @tables table (
    rowId int identity(1,1),
    name nvarchar(max)
);

insert      @tables
select      schema_name(schema_id) + '.' + name 
from        sys.tables
where       type_desc = 'user_table'
```

Now you're ready to loop the tables and apply #scriptTable:

```
declare @rowId int = 1;
declare @table nvarchar(max);
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

while @rowId <= (select max(rowId) from @tables) begin
    select @table = name from @tables where rowId = @rowId;
    exec #scriptTable @table, @sql output;
    print (@sql); -- turn 'print' into 'exec' or otherwise use sp_executeSql
    set @rowId += 1;
end
```

As before, replace 'print' with 'exec' or use sp_executeSql when ready.

Note that my portion may need further modification if you have table names that will require brackets around them.

**EDIT:**
Updated the code a bit to simplify (slightly) and to work with table names needing brackets around them.

Comment: There you go, that answer by devart in turn links to a couple of great articles that people interested in this sort of stuff should read.

Answer (score 1):

For creation of CCI on all tables, you may use the below :

```
    DECLARE @SQLscript nVARCHAR(1000) =
'CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX &&& ON @@@ WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF,COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0)'

declare @tables table (
    rowId int identity(1,1),
    name nvarchar(max)
);

insert      @tables
select      schema_name(schema_id) + '.' + name 
from        sys.tables
where       type_desc = 'user_table'

declare @rowId int = 1;
declare @table nvarchar(max);
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

while @rowId <= (select max(rowId) from @tables) begin
    select @table = name from @tables where rowId = @rowId;
    SET @SQLscript = REPLACE(REPLACE(@SQLscript, '@@@',@table) ,'&&&','cci_' + SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@table,'].[','_'),CHARINDEX('.',REPLACE(@table,'].[','_'))+1,LEN(REPLACE(@table,'].[','_'))))
 BEGIN TRY 
  EXEC  sp_executeSql @SQLscript; 
  END TRY 
  BEGIN CATCH 
  PRINT @SQLscript
  END CATCH 

    SET @SQLscript = 'CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX &&& ON @@@ WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF,COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0)'
    set @rowId += 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @pwilcox is right, except for the last part where it spits out the code for the rowstore index. That index should not be clustered as the line above already creates the clustered columnstore index.

Fix:

```
-- Replaced "create primary key" logic in the original with what's below:

    +   ISNULL(
            (
                select  'create clustered columnstore index [ccx_' + @table_name + '] on ' + @object_name + char(13) +
                        'create unique index [' + replace(k.name, 'pk_', 'unx_') + '] ' +
                            'on ' + @object_name + ' (' + 
                                (
                                    SELECT STUFF((
                                        SELECT  ', [' + ic.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END
                                        FROM    index_column ic
                                        WHERE   ic.is_included_column = 0
                                        AND     ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id 
                                        AND     ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id     
                                        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE
                                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
                                ) + 
                            ')' + CHAR(13)
                FROM sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT)
                join sys.indexes i with (nowait) on k.unique_index_id = i.index_id and k.parent_object_id = i.object_id
                WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id 
                    AND k.[type] = 'PK'
            ), 
            ''
        );
```